# How to create new entity (node type) using drupal rule

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-rules

I have content type award with few fields (user, position, lesson).
I have create a rule to create new node in rule actions.

When i select node type in rule it's show only two fieds : title and author.

How i get all other fields in rules action or condition .

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to create additional actions to set data values for the additional fields you want filled in.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like (part of) what you're trying to do, is to add a Rules Action like "Set a data value" for the fields you mentioned (like lesson, etc).

But before you will be able to create a Rules Action like "Set a data value" for your field(s), you have to make sure to add a Rules Condition `Entity has field` (related to the  field for which you want to set a value). And make sure to add that `Entity has field` condition BEFORE other Rules Conditions in which you might want to refer to this field. Depending on what exactly you want to do in your custom rule, an alternative might be to use `content is of type`.

That's also what is mentioned in the Rules UI, e.g. when you're adding a "data comparison" condition: somewhere it says:

> *The data selector helps you drill down into the data available to Rules. To make entity fields appear in the data selector, you may have to use the condition 'entity has field' (or 'content is of type')*.

For a video tutorial that illustrates the importance of this `Entity has field` condition, refer to [Data types and data selection](http://drupal.placeto.be/tutorial/data-types-and-data-selection), especially what is shown between about 13:30 and 17:30 in it.